# Replacing words inside the string with that of dictionary without using any kind of replace function

Tags: python

```html
expected output = "Hello. My name is $xyz$. I am from $abc$.

# code
string = 'Hi. My name is #something1#. I am from #something2#. My company is #something3#.'
toReplace = {'something1':'xyz', 'something2': 'abc', 'something3': 'ttl'}
modified = list(string)
arr=[]
for i in range(len(string)):
    if string[i]=='#':
        arr.append(i)
#print(arr)

indices = []
for i in range(len(arr)):
    if i%2 != 0:
        continue
    else:
        indices.append(arr[i]+1)
#print(indices)

sources = []        
l = 0
while l<len(arr):
    sources.append(string[arr[l]+1:arr[l+1]])
    #print(l, sources)
    l+=2
#print(sources)

targets = toReplace.values()
#print(targets)

for index, source, target in zip(indices, sources, targets):
    #print(index, source, target)
    if not string[index:].startswith(source):
        continue
    else:
        modified[index] = target
        #print(modified)
        for i in range(index+1,len(source)+index):
            modified[i] = ''
            
print("".join(modified))
```

should get this without using replace() or re.replace() functions. it should not remove placeholders. only word inside dictionary to be replace but to be done without replace functions. Any ideas??

Comment: What is the role of `$` here?

Comment: but why not use `replace()`? can you explain the scenario you're stuck in and your tries?

Comment: consider $ as just a placeholder.

Comment: can do it with replace just wanted to try without replace function as well

Comment: So, what exactly is the problem? You are putting some pretty arbitrary restrictions here, people aren't going to just do this for you. That isn't what StackOverflow is for.

Comment: I have done this using above method. but need some shorter way to do it, ideas are appreciated.

Comment: There is a stack exchange site called [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) you may want to do this question there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're there. I'd suggest if instead of listing all characters in the sentence you can `split()` it with `#` delimiter, the solution becomes a lot simpler.

```py
'$'.join([toReplace[k] if k in toReplace.keys() else k for k in string.split('#')])
# 'Hi. My name is $xyz$. I am from $abc$. My company is $ttl$.'
```

- `string.split('#')` will generate a list of strings, broken at every `'#'`
- The list comprehension will search for the list's strings in the dict's keys, and if found, it will pull the item from the dictionary
- The resulting list after the comprehension can then be joined using the `'#'` delimiter as it was split. You could also update the join string to be `'$'`.

Answer (score 1):

Good day to you! I'm glad if the following code will help you in anyway. I have used regular expression to get the required output. Here you go,

```
import re    
string = "Hello. My name is $something1$. I am from $something2$." 
    dict = {'something1':'xyz', 'something2':'abc'}
    for k,v in zip(dict.keys(),dict.values()):
        string=re.sub(k,v,string)
    print(string)
```

And Output is :

```
Hello. My name is $xyz$. I am from $abc$.
```

I'm really glad for this opportunity to help you! Thank you!

Comment: A tip: don't use `dict` (or any build-in type name) as a variable name. I'm saying this because a lot of new people read SO questions so you should ignore bad practices

Comment: Oh, thank you! I will avoid it in future.